# Nielsen's Model of Usability vs Eason's Model of Usability: Which is more relevant and the most widely used?

Tags: usability, research

I'm working for my final project. In the analysis, i have to choose one model to be used as a reference implementation. So, which is more relevant to be implemented, Nielsen's Model of Usability or Eason's Model of Usability? and which is the most widely used?

Please, explain to me the reason. I need some reference too.

Comment: Does it really matter for your project which model you use? I don't think so. Your tasks is to choose one and analyze your implementation using it.

Comment: @dnbrv of course. I need to know which models are most widely used so I can find out the advantages of the model is compared to other models.

Comment: you should link to the actual source if you're talking about it. If the source is huge and you need to pay for it, you should at least use the examples that grab your attention the most and comment on them :)

Comment: This reads like a homework question - "compare and contrast Eason and Nielsen's usability models". Also, if you're referring to specific methodologies / models etc then it's advisable to at least link to references discussing them (and really you should actually summarize these models within your question).

Comment: i read the models from the bok by author Lara Leventhal and Julie Barnes with the title Usability Engineering Process, Products, and Examples. I also have ebook that discusses these models. [link](http://www.cs.bgsu.edu/jbarnes/cs324/lectures/Ch3_Lect_4_5_6.ppt) .. in the ebook mentioned that the most widely accepted model is Eason's Model, but in a lot of searches mentioned that Nielsen's Model is most widely used reference. so, it makes me confuse to choose which is more relevant nowadays. @JonW

Comment: If we answer this for you, you won't learn anything ;)

Comment: i have read a lot of sources about the models, but it just explained about the model generally. I need a supporting facts to prove why many people choose a model. e.g: I'm choosing Eason's Model of Usability, and then i'm writing an explanation of why I chose the Model. But, on the other hand I also need supporting facts which proves that this model's also used by many people. Btw, thanks before :)  @Peter

Comment: If you can improve your question, cite your references and provide an actual answerable query here then we can re-open this to get more answers. As it stands it's just a 'tell me about these two types of X' question which isn't a useful Q&A question.

Comment: Common guys (@JonW, @Peter) this fellow is just starting out here and he is very frank about it being a school assignment. You just probably turned off someone who might be an awesome contributor. He just wants an industry opinion to include in his writings to balance his own argument for which model is preffered/most used. I think that is rather responsible. I see more and more questions turned down in a negative way instead of trying to be constructive.

Comment: @JeroenEijkhof We're happy to help out with questions, and the comments here show that for around 10 hours this question was left open awaiting an update - just providing sources or a summary about the two models would probably suffice - but this is yet to happen so the question has been *temporarily* closed to new answers while the OP can source the references / summaries needed to improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Nielsen's.

Neilsen has been pretty active in the field over the last 20 years.  (Mr ?) Eason seems to have written about this in 1988 - and then not been seen since.

http://www.nigelbevan.com/papers/whatis92.pdf

The ISO definition is the most common 'model' of what usability is:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability